# MySQL syntax for Join Update

Tags: sql, mysql

I have two tables that look like this

Train

```
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field    | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| TrainID  | varchar(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| Capacity | int(11)     | NO   |     | 50      |       |
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Reservations

```
+---------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field         | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| ReservationID | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| FirstName     | varchar(30) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| LastName      | varchar(30) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| DDate         | date        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| NoSeats       | int(2)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| Route         | varchar(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| Train         | varchar(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+---------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Currently, I'm trying to create a query that will increment the capacity on a Train if a reservation is cancelled. I know I have to perform a Join, but I'm not sure how to do it in an Update statement. For Example, I know how to get the capacity of a Train with given a certain ReservationID, like so:

```
select Capacity 
  from Train 
  Join Reservations on Train.TrainID = Reservations.Train 
 where ReservationID = "15";
```

But I'd like to construct the query that does this -

```
Increment Train.Capacity by ReservationTable.NoSeats given a ReservationID
```

If possible, I'd like to know also how to Increment by an arbitrary number of seats. As an aside, I'm planning on deleting the reservation after I perform the increment in a Java transaction. Will the delete effect the transaction?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I know this is a 9 year old post, but for something like train capacity, you don't want to be updating a column for this unless you have a really good reason. As you pointed out, it's a single join. This is something that will update A LOT - per reservation, so this should be on the fly select query with join, rather than update. Excessive updates lock tables.

Answer (score 247, accepted):

MySQL supports a [multi-table `UPDATE` syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html), which would look approximately like this:

```
UPDATE Reservations r JOIN Train t ON (r.Train = t.TrainID)
SET t.Capacity = t.Capacity + r.NoSeats
WHERE r.ReservationID = ?;
```

You can update the `Train` table and delete from the `Reservations` table in the same transaction.  As long as you do the update first and then do the delete second, it should work.

Comment: Bah, I put the `SET` before the `JOIN` by mistake. NB folks

Comment: If you're in MySQL safe mode (default), then you can use `WHERE alias.primary_key_id > 0` to effectively circumvent safe mode and update all rows.

Answer (score 11):

Here is another example of an UPDATE statement that contains joins to determine the value that is being updated.  In this case, I want to update the transactions.payee_id with the related account payment id, if the payee_id is zero (wasn't assigned).

```
UPDATE transactions t
  JOIN account a ON a.id = t.account_id
  JOIN account ap ON ap.id = a.pmt_act_id
  SET  t.payee_id = a.pmt_act_id
 WHERE t.payee_id = 0
```

Comment: If you may be wondering what the significance of the 2nd JOIN to account (aliased as ap), that was just because I first wrote the query as a SELECT (which is always good practice) prior to converting to UPDATE statement.