# MySQL: Updating id value in one table from another table

Tags: mysql, sql, join, sql-update, crud

I have a table `table1` `o_id` as `PK`,  `ipaddress`, `b_id`

```
o_id    ip              b_id
9205    10.10.10.10     null
9206    10.10.10.11     null
9207    10.10.10.12     null
```

---more than 1000 rows

I have another table `table2` `id` as `PK`,  `ipaddress`, `b_id`

```
id      ip              o_id
18356   10.10.10.10     null
18357   10.10.10.11     null
18358   10.10.10.12     null
```

---more than 1000 rows

Now, if `ipaddress` matches in both tables, then I want to update both tables such that `table2.o_id = table1.o_id` and `table1.b_id = table2.id`

```
update table1  
set b_id = table2.id
where ip = table2.ip
```

Here I want to update `o_id` in second table from the `o_id` in first table.
I also want to update `b_id` in first table from `id` in second table.

Is above query correct? there a way to update both tables in single query?

Comment: Can i ask why you want such update after that you will have same data in 2 tables  ?

Comment: Are you asking how to do a JOIN in an UPDATE? I posted an example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2114534/mysql-syntax-for-join-update/2114583#2114583

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking too your request 
you could use update with join

```
update table1 t1
inner join table2 t2 on t1.ip = t2.ip 
set t1.o_id = t2.o_id, 
    t1.b_id = t2-id
```

but looking to your data you have table2.o_id = null so with the update you make all the o_id (primary key ) null  .. and this is not possible (and no sense to me)

if you need  update b_id in first table from id in second table then should be

```
update table2 t2
inner join table1 t1 on t1.ip = t2.ip 
set t2.o_id = t1.o_id, 
    t2.id = t1.b_id
```

Comment: Here I want to update `o_id` in second table from the `o_id` in first table.
I also want to update `b_id` in first table from `id` in second table. I have also updated my question. Can you plz help?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need an update at all! First to be able to correctly (and meaningfully) update ref IDs based on the IP address field that would require that IP address is unique in the both tables. So, if it is unique you can use it to join tables anyway, and get IDs from each tables. So no need to store it when you can get it by simply joining the tables.