# MS Access UPDATE Query errors

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am having a hard time using MS Access because the syntax is a little finicky compared to other db's.

I am trying to validate a table and compare that table to a master table with multiple columns of information. At the moment I am trying to update a table with a field name of `Difference_Value` in table `ct2011` to be equal to `(ct2011.Distribution_Amount - AggregateFinal.SumOfDollars)`.

Also specifying the lines in which are going to be updated because not all rows in the MASTER are in the table `ct2011`.

Below is my query.

```
UPDATE ct2011
SET ct2011.Difference_Value = (ct2011.Distribution_Amount - AggregateFinal.SumOfDollars)
FROM
       ct2011 as ct
INNER JOIN 
       AggregateFinal af
ON
       ct.Employee_ID = af.EmpId AND ct.Legal_Name = af.LegalName AND ct.Distribution_Plan_Year = af.CalculationAwardPeriod AND ct.Award_Year = af.AwardPeriod;
```

I am getting a `Syntax error (missing operator)`. It specifies that it is encountering the error during the `SET expressions` after the `=`.

Comment: And what exactly is not working with the given query? Is there any error message?

Comment: @NicoHaase I am getting a Syntax error (missing operator). It specifies that it is encountering the error during the SET expressions after the =.

Comment: You set a table alias of `ct` for ct2011, but kept using `ct2011` to fully qualify the field names.

Comment: There is no `FROM` clause in `UPDATE` queries in MS Access. And before you claim that is *finicky*, MySQL also adheres to this same [`UPDATE ... JOIN`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2114534/1422451) style. Still *finicky*? Try writing a join in [`UPDATE` query in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2446764/1422451) which neither supports `JOIN` or `FROM` unless inside a subquery, similar also to [SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19270259/1422451). Yes, all SQL dialects are *finicky*!

Answer (score 1):

In an MS Access `update` query, the `join` criteria should follow the `update` keyword, e.g.:

```sql
update 
    ct2011 ct inner join aggregatefinal af on
    ct.employee_id = af.empid and 
    ct.legal_name = af.legalname and 
    ct.distribution_plan_year = af.calculationawardperiod and
    ct.award_year = af.awardperiod
set 
    ct.difference_value = (ct.distribution_amount - af.sumofdollars)
```