# Subselect in Update Statment with where

Tags: php, mysql, sql, oxid

How can I make this PHP script in a one Single SQL statement?

```
$sql = 'SELECT oxtprice from oxarticles where oxparentid = ? and nrseriesarticle = 1';
        $price = DatabaseProvider::getDb()->getOne($sql, [$id]);

        if ($price) {
            $updateSql = "Update oxarticles SET nrseriestprice = ? WHERE oxid = ? and oxparentid = ''";
            DatabaseProvider::getDb()->execute($updateSql, [$price, $id]);
```

I want something like this but it didn't work

```
UPDATE oxarticles SET 
nrseriesprice = (SELECT oxprice from oxarticles where oxparentid = ? and nrseriesarticle = 1) 
WHERE oxid = ?
```

Comment: Is there always a return from the oxarticles for oxprice?

Comment: I think you really need to explain what the columns in this `oxarticles` represent. I can only guess what the relation is between a row with a certain value in `oxid` and another row with the same value in `oxparentid`. It is also well known that just saying that something "didn't work" is not very helpful. Didn't work how?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2114534/mysql-syntax-for-join-update

Comment: @Nathan_Sav no not always there are a value

Answer (score 1):

You only need one query like below

> ```
> CREATE TABLE parent (oxid int ,nrseriesprice DECIMAL (10,2))
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO parent VALUES (1,NULL)
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE oxarticles (oxprice DECIMAL(19,2), oxparentid int,nrseriesarticle int)
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO oxarticles VALUES (19.2,1,1)
> ```

> ```
> UPDATE parent p SET 
> nrseriesprice = (SELECT oxprice from oxarticles where oxparentid = p.oxid and nrseriesarticle = 1) 
> WHERE p.oxid = 1
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM parent
> ```
>
> ```
> oxid | nrseriesprice
> ---: | ------------:
>    1 |         19.20
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a9663babb6e05f8601677411f791bfb9)*