# How to change the column value to different value if the same value is present in another table?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to update the column value(slot time) present in "schedule" table to zero time as the slot time is inserted to another table "appointment" so that the booked slot times will be set to unavailable in "schedule" tabel

```
<?php

$docid = $_SESSION['did'];
$date = $_SESSION['dt'];
$slot = $_SESSION['st'];

/*echo$docid;
echo$date;*/
$sql1 = "SELECT * FROM `appointment`;";
$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM `schedule`;";


$result1 = mysqli_query($conn,$sql1);
$result2 = mysqli_query($conn,$sql2);

while($rows1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1)){

    if($rows1['docid']=$docid && $rows1['date']=$date){
        echo $docid;
        echo $date;
        echo $slot;
        echo "match";
        while ($rows2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)) {
            for ($i=3; $i <10 ; $i++) { 
                if ($rows2[$i]=$slot){
                    echo $rows2[$i];
                    $sql = "UPDATE `schedule` SET ________='00:00:00';"
                    mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
                    echo $i;
                    break;
                }
                
            }break;     
        }
    }
    break;
}
```

Comment: Maybe `join` the other table then you'd know if there was a match.. don't forget a `where` clause on the `update`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL syntax for Join Update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2114534/mysql-syntax-for-join-update)

Comment: I found the match to the column value in another table but couldn't get the respective column name